# What species is this mammal?

Tags: species-identification, mammals

I saw a mammal that looked like a large squirrel. I haven't seen anything quite like it. Can you help me identify it?

- Squirrel-like, "hunched over" posture.
- It was too large to be an eastern squirrel—approximately 2.5 feet, from nose to tail.
- It had a fluffy tail like an eastern squirrel, not short and rat-like like a ferret.
- Black face with white nose, body was chestnut-brown.
- I saw this on the ground, not in a tree.
- I saw it in a pine forest in east-central Alabama.
- At one point, it sat up on its hind legs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds pretty much like a fox squirrel (or better: as masked face fox squirrel which are found in Alabama).
They look like this (taken from this [website](http://gardeningsoul.blogspot.de/2011/05/masked-face-fox-squirrel.html)):

[image]

There seems to be quite some variation in terms of fur color, some animals are more greyish:

[image]

Taken from [here](http://www.outdooralabama.com/watchable-wildlife/what/Mammals/Rodents/fs.cfm), this website also contains some additional information.